# Flexbox layout without media queries

Tags: flexbox, media-queries

is it possible to do this layout https://codepen.io/Eu-g/pen/jOEdaEW?editors=1100 with flexbox and without media queries?

```
<nav>
<div class="first">first prev</div>
<div class="last">next last</div>
<div class="page">1 2 3 4 5 6 7</div>
</nav>

nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid navy;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.first {
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  float: left;
}

.last {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  float: right;
}

.page {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for? https://codepen.io/breadadams/pen/dyPrNOK?editors=1100

Comment: Almost, I need that the numbers in small viewports break below navigation (prev & next). Check my codepen in small viewports and you can see what I mean.